# Text Based Poker Game

Tags: poker-tools

Any text based poker games out there? I'm at work with absolutely nothing to do right now, but I don't want to look like a slacker.

Comment: I deal, you get 5♧ Q♢.  Action is on you.

Comment: What's my position? hahaha
Wait I'm guessing I'm under the gun, I fold lol.

Comment: After you muck I turn over my cards to reveal I had 10♥ 6♢.

Comment: Oh this is sit & go, god damn it

Comment: I order a handle of vodka, chug it all in 3 big gulps burp loudly and say "Ok baby, it's scotty time"

Comment: I deal you get ace of spades, and ace of hearts

Comment: lol. what are the odds of that?

Comment: I raise 3BB, you call.  The flop comes A♢K♤Q ♥.  I go all in, you call and turn over your cards, revealing J♧10♧.  The turn is 5♤ and the river is 2♢.   I am obviously on tilt.

Comment: So am I cause I wanted to rig it so I get a royal flush, I smash my handle of vodka in half and use it as a weapon. I start stabbing you repeatedly, take your money and run. good game well played

Comment: well... that escalated quickly!

Answer (score 3):

You might try the World.Rec.Gambling poker tournament @ http://www.wrgpt.org/.  It's email based, and a lot of fun.  Been around pretty much since the internet was invented.

Comment: This site is unfortunately blocked at my work :(